# What is the albedo of our Sun?

Tags: astrophysics, reflection, thermal-radiation, sun

I think the Sun is the closest to a perfect natural black body we can get in the Solar System, if so then what happens to the light if I point a laser pointer at the Sun?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the sun is close to a black body and would absorb the laser pointer light.

If one looks at [the solar reference spectrum](https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2017/12/Solar_spectrum) it is almost a perfect blackbody spectrum (but not quite - there are a few absorption lines). That means that the optical environment where the light comes from is strongly coupled: photons have had the time to interact with matter enough to have their energies and direction throughly randomized. So the photosphere is opaque.

Outside the photosphere photons can escape to space with a high probability: they are not following a random walk but ballistic motion. Similarly an incoming laser beam will be able to pass through these layers without much interaction, but clearly there will be some scattering from the plasma. So you could in principle illuminate the chromosphere with a sufficiently bright laser and see scattered light, but once it hits the optically dense photosphere the light gets randomized and diffuses.

Comment: Thought about writing a new answer... but I had just one thing to say. Emissivity equals absroptivity (Kirchoff's law). This is why the sun's perfect blackbody spectrum is proof that the sun will also absorb any light you send toward it. It's just one step in the logic that I thought your answer was missing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation

Comment: @AXensen the Sun doesn't have a perfect blackbody spectrum at all. The interior of the Sun is a perfect blackbody, the photosphere isn't.

Comment: @ProfRob - I think the curve is good enough to work for the argument?

Comment: Kirchoff's law is not absolute, it is true for homogenous, isothermal bodies and the Sun is not one of them. The solar spectrum is a good starting point, but the bands in the spectrum do not mean that the Sun as a whole is reflective at this wavelength. It simply means that at this wavelength the optical depth protrudes colder layers. The Sun is certain to reflect some light, e.g. this is how radar measurements are taken, but on the other hand it is somewhat more black than the visible spectrum suggests.